# checkboxes under each other

Tags: html, css, razor

I try to make checkboxes under each other like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         @foreach (var item in Model.Directories)
         {                                                                                              
            @Html.CheckBox("Assigned", Model.IsActive.HasValue ? Model.IsActive : false);
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Directories)
         }
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

but now the checkboxes are all under the same line.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish for the checkboxes to appear in a new line, rather than appending to the same `td` cell, you should append to create a new `tr` instead:

```
<table>
   @foreach (var item in Model.Directories) { 
  <tr>
    <td>
     @Html.CheckBox("Assigned", Model.IsActive.HasValue ? Model.IsActive : false); 
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Directories) 
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
</table>
```

which will create a new table row for each model Item